# Ограничить генератор списков, чтобы он возвращал не более N элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно вывести слова из списка (`d`), которые начинаются из определенных букв (`i`). При этом всё, что не буквы, учитывать в вводе не надо, а макс. количество слов на выводе должно быть 5.

Код:

```
def autocomplete(i, d):
    p = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
    t = ''.join([x for x in i if x.lower() in p])
    q = [
    w for w in d 
    if t in w[:len(t)].lower()
    ]
    if len(q)<=5:
        return q
    else:
        return q[:5]


    print(autocomplete('a3i',[ 'abnormal', 'arm-wrestling', 'absolute', 
    'airplane', 'airport', 'amazing', 'apple', 'ball' ]))
```

С задачей справился, но при выполнении возникло несколько вопросов:

1. Возможно ли ограничивать сам генератор списков (в коде - `q`) количеством элементов в нем? Чтобы он сам переставал дополнять список и ненужно было снизу дописывать `if-else`.

   Пробовал интуитивно обращаться к самой переменной в условии (`len(q)< 5`):

   ```
     q = [w for w in d if t in w[:len(t)].lower() and len(q)< 5]
   ```

   Но так не работает, т.к `q` еще не объявлена переменной.

   `while` никак вроде не вставить, и счетчик в генератор тоже.
2. Можно ли ограничивать ввод (`i`) определенными символами, т.е. теми, которые можно вводить или наоборот нельзя?
   Если нельзя ограничить, то можно ли как-нибудь более упростить работу с символами, чем у меня?

Comment: Вы можете просто `q[:5]`. Условие не надо, тк это корректный вызов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
import string

def autocomplete(i, d, threshold=5):
    i = i.casefold()
    t = ''.join([x for x in i if x in string.ascii_lowercase])
    return [w for cnt,w in enumerate(d) if w.casefold().startswith(t) and cnt < threshold]
```

или используя регулярные выражения:

```
import re

def autocomplete(i, d, threshold=5):
    t = re.sub('[^a-z]', '', i.casefold())
    return [w for cnt,w in enumerate(d) if w.casefold().startswith(t) and cnt < threshold]
```